# Как правильно применить sum() в postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS models (
  id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(15)
);

INSERT INTO models (id, name) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'samsung');
...

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS phones (
  id       SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  model_id INTEGER   NOT NULL,
  prise    INTEGER   NOT NULL,
  date     TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (model_id) REFERENCES models (id)
);

INSERT INTO phones (id, model_id, prise, date)
VALUES (DEFAULT, 1, 58000, now());
...
```

Мне нужно составить запрос который будет отдавать сумму продаж за период. Я попытался сделать это так:

```
SELECT
  sum(p.prise)
FROM phones AS p, models AS m
WHERE p.date >= '2017-11-02 23:21:31.59098' AND m.name = 'samsung';
```

Но не сработало.

Помогите пожалуйста составить такой запрос и объясните почему моя версия оказалась неверной. Спасибо.

Comment: почему в запросе нет условия соединения таблиц p и m ? без него происходит перемножение всех подходящих записей первой таблицы на все подходящие записи второй

Comment: И в любой непонятной ситуации делайте `select *` и смотрите результат, сразу обнаружите проблему

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY (model_id) REFERENCES models (id)` А Вы не забыли, что INTEGER знаковый (Range: -2147483648 to +2147483647), а SERIAL нет (Range: 1 to 2147483647)?